# Can the this pointer be polymorphic?

Tags: c++

I thought that typeid was supposed to reveal the most derived type of it's parameter. But when I use it in a constructor like the below, it seems unaware of what the real type of the pointer is.

When I pass it off to another class, it also seems to not know what the type is.

Is this because the this pointer doesn't know what the real type is? Is there a way around this to determine the real derived type of the this pointer?

In this below code, is there a way for `Thing<T>` to determine the derived type of the pointer passed to it?

```
#include <concepts>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class FooBase;

class ThingBase
{
public:
    virtual int GetThing(const FooBase* const foo) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
requires std::derived_from<T, FooBase>
class Thing : public ThingBase
{
public:
    virtual int GetThing(const FooBase* const foo) const override
    {
        if(typeid(T) == typeid(*foo))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};

class FooBase
{
public:
    FooBase(const ThingBase* const thing)
    :
        i(thing->GetThing(this))
    {
        std::cout << "Foo base is: " << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~FooBase() {}

    virtual const int& GetBaseValue() const final
    {
        return i;
    }

protected:
    int i;
};

class Foo : public FooBase
{
public:
    Foo(const ThingBase* const thing)
    :
        FooBase(thing),
        j(thing->GetThing(this))
    {
        std::cout << "Foo is: " << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl;
    }

    const int& GetChildValue() const
    {
        return j;
    }

protected:
    int j;
};

int main()
{
    Thing<Foo> thing;

    Foo foo1(&thing);

    std::cout << foo1.GetBaseValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo1.GetChildValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo1 is: " << typeid(foo1).name() << std::endl;

    FooBase* foo2 = new Foo(&thing);

    std::cout << foo2->GetBaseValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo2 is: " << typeid(*foo2).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `virtual const int& GetBaseValue() const final` - Random aside, why do you declare a function both virtual and final in the base class?

Comment: @SebastianRedl for no reason, it's late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the this pointer be polymorphic?

Yes, if the pointed class is a polymorphic class... but not during its onstruction because when the constructor of the base is running, then the derived class constructor will not have completed yet.

> Is there a way around this to determine the real derived type of the this pointer?

Wait for the type to be complete i.e. don't use `typeid` in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

[The docs:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

> If typeid is used on an object under construction or destruction (in a destructor or in a constructor, including constructor's initializer list or default member initializers), then the std::type_info object referred to by this typeid represents the class that is being constructed or destroyed even if it is not the most-derived class.

The way around this (in the order of relevance) is:

1. Don't use `typeid`, like ever.
2. Use `typeid` only on completely constructed objects.

Comment: That's not really a way around it. Is there a way for `Thing<T>` to determine the derived type?

Comment: @NeomerArcana what exactly you misunderstand from the answer I gave you? No, there is no way to do that during construction. The real point of my answer is that you are trying to solve incorrect problem. You should not care about concrete types. You should care about functionalities only. That's why it is unlikely to see `typeid` in real code, the operator is not as useful as you seem to think.